# How to delete an element from a vector of custom objects

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I'm trying to delete an item from a 1std::vector`with`std::vector::erase()` but I keep getting an error.

```
class Person
{
  private:
    string name;

  public:
    void set_name(string name) { this->name = name; }
    string get_name() { return name; }
};
```

```
class Record
{
private:
  vector <Person> book;
public:
    void delete_person(string name)
    {
        for (Person p : book)
            if (book.get_name() == name)
                book.erase(p);
    }    
};
```

```
int main()
{
    // Nothing in main yet    
    return 0;
}
```

I get en error in the delete_person() function in the record class: No matching member function for call to 'erase'

Comment: [Note how none of the `erase` overloads take a `Person`, or rather the tamplated type.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) They take iterators and ranges of iterators.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried this but it didn't work either book.erase(book.begin(), book.end(), p);

Comment: Important fact about range-based `for` loops: They're really dumb. They go from start to finish and are extremely intolerant of changes to the container while iterating. If you add or remove an item while iterating it, the hidden bookkeeping used by the loop becomes invalid and the loop breaks. And not the nice `break` sort of breaking. They tend to take the whole program with them.

Comment: FYI, if you choose a different coding style where member names are different than parameter names, you don't to use the `this->` syntax.  Remember, the more you type, the higher the probability of injecting a typo defect.

Comment: Use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the named `Person`. It returns an iterator you can use to erase. Better still [use `std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: Should look something like `book.erase(std::remove_if(book.begin(), book.end(), [name](const Person & p){return p.get_name() == name;} );`

Comment: @user4581301 with the same for loop?

Comment: No need for loop. The looping is done for you in `std::remove_if`. Lot of really good stuff found in [the `<algorithm>` include](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that can make your life much easier. Worth the time spent reading through it and experimenting.

Comment: Side note: If you've never seen one before the `[name](const Person & p){return p.get_name() == name;}` is a [Lambda Expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: @user4581301 yeah I see

Comment: I missed a part of the `erase`/`remove_if`: `book.erase(std::remove_if(book.begin(), book.end(), [name](const Person & p){return p.get_name() == name;} ), book.end());`. `erase` needs to know where to stop erasing.

Comment: @user4581301 I got this error: 'this' argument to member function 'get_name' has type 'const Person', but function is not marked const

Comment: Some additional reading: [The Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) explains what's going on and why we do it that way.

Comment: Apologies. Change `string get_name(){ return name; }` into `string get_name() const { return name; }` `const` on a class member function means the function promises that it will not change the class, and making changes to the class is something getter function usually shouldn't do. Rule of thumb: Make everything `const` unless you know it should be changed. This lets the compiler catch accidental changes and give you a compiler error rather than you wasting time debugging.

Comment: @user4581301 can you please right the entire expression again because I got confused. I don't see   string get_name(){ return name; } in the code

Comment: @sam Formally answered the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
void delete_person(string name){
        for(Person p : book){
            if(book.get_name() == name){
                book.erase(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

fails for several reasons.

`std::vector::erase` does not accept items, it accepts iterators, locations of items to be removed.

Range-based for loops are very simple and limited in their abilities. They go from start to finish and are extremely intolerant of changes to the container while iterating. If you add or remove an item while iterating it, the hidden bookkeeping used by the loop becomes invalid and the loop breaks. And not the nice `break` sort of breaking. They tend to take the whole program down with them.

In `Person p : book` `p` is a new object that is a copy of an item in `book`. It's not the original or a reference to the original in the container. C++ defaults to values instead of references in almost every case. Unless you specifically request otherwise, you pass by value, return by value, and iterate by value.

Instead, employ the [Erase-Remove Idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). Here is an example with added commentary where I saw it fitting or educational.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    Person(const std::string & name) // added for testing
        : name(name) // this is a member initializer list In C++ all class members 
                     // and base classes must be initialized before the program can 
                     // enter the body of the constructor. This trick allows us to 
                     // initialize members rather than initializing them to their 
                     // defaults (if the type has a default) and then setting them 
                     // inside the body and wasting time doing two things where one 
                     // thing was required
    {

    }
    void set_name(string name) // side note consider saving construction of a new 
                               // string and accepting name by const reference rather 
                               // than by value and potentially making a copy. 
                               // void set_name(const string & name) 
                               // const because we do not intend to change `name`
                               // and because the compiler can take advantage of the 
                               // promise not to change it in many interesting ways.  
    {
        this->name = name;
    }
    string get_name() const // const because getters generally should not change the 
                            // object this allows us to keep the class "const-correct"
                            // side note consider saving construction of a new 
                            // string and returning by const reference rather than 
                            // by value and making a copy.
                            // const string & get_name() const 
    {
        return name;
    }
};
class Record
{
private:
    vector<Person> book;
public:
    void add_person(const std::string & name) // added for testing
    {
        book.emplace_back(name);
    }
    void delete_person(string name) // again consider passing name by const reference 
    {
        book.erase(std::remove_if(book.begin(), // from start of list
                                  book.end(),   // to the end
                                  [name](const Person &p)
                                  {
                                      return p.get_name() == name;
                                  }), //  moves all items to be removed to the end of the 
                                      // list, then returns start of range to erase
                   book.end()); // erase to the end of the list
    // Why erase separately? Because remove functions don't actually remove. They 
    // move the unwanted values to the end of the list. Looks silly, but much easier 
    // and safer to write. For example, this won't change the size of the list and 
    // break loops that count on the size to remain the same.
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                                     const Record & rec) // added for testing
    {
        for (const auto & item: rec.book) // print all items in book
                                          // const because printing should not change 
                                          // the printed
                                          // auto to let the compiler figure out the type
                                          // & because we don't want to make a copy
        {
            out << item.get_name() << '\n';
        }
        return out;
    }
};
int main()
{

    Record r;
    r.add_person("Bill");
    r.add_person("Ted");
    r.add_person("Rufus");
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
    r.delete_person("Ted");
    std::cout << r << std::endl; // Ted should now be gone from the list
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Bill
Ted
Rufus

Bill
Rufus
```

Comment: Very informative and educational thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
book.erase(p);
```

`book` is a vector. The parameter to a vector's `erase()` method is an ***iterator***.

```
for(Person p : book){
```

`p` is the ***value*** in the vector, and actually it is a ***copy*** of the value in the vector. You cannot pass a value to `erase()`. You must pass an iterator as a parameter. Passing some random copy of some random value in a vector to its `erase()` method is not going to accomplish anything useful.

`std::vector` has `begin()` and `end()` methods that return the iterator to the beginning and the end of a sequence that defines the contents of the vector.

This may be used with various algorithms, like [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), together with `std::vector::erase` to effect the removal of a value or multiple values from your vector.

Comment: aha now I understand. This is how I did it in java with the remove() function so I thought it's the same. thank you

Comment: @Sam If your compiler is right up to date you can use [`std::erase` and `std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) to make things a bit easier, but you still can't use them in a range-based `for` loop.

Comment: C++ is not Java. C++ works fundamentally differently from Java. You will find that you will learn C++ much more effectively if you completely forget everything you know about Java, when trying to learn C++.